# Datagrid from list crashes when item selected

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2019

BindingList was the correct answer, it fixed all of the problems, including being able to format the columns. Here are the only lines I had to change, and everything is working perfectly now.

```
//This went at the top:
BindingList<Ingredient> selectedIngredients = new BindingList<Ingredient>();

//This went in the page Load method:
dgvRecipeIngredients.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = selectedIngredients};

//These three went as appropriate in methods that added or removed items from the list. 
//The ResetBindings removed items from the list, which wasn’t happening before without resetting the page. 

selectedIngredients.Add(ingr);
selectedIngredients.RemoveAt(idxSelectedIngr);
selectedIngredients.ResetBindings();
```

I have left everything else as it was, so people can see the problems, and how this fixed them.

[Picture of UI with some data in second grid (bottom) and an ingredient ready to be added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeMDF.png) I have one gridview that I am bringing my list of ingredients into that is working just fine.
I have a second gridvew that I want to be able to add ingredients to from the first gridview.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HealthierRecipes
{
    public partial class AddRecipe : Form
    {
        public static int ingrId = 0;
        public static int availIngrId = -1;
        private static int idxSelectedIngr = 0;
        private static int idxSelectedAvailIngr = -1;
        private List<Ingredient> selectedIngredients = new List<Ingredient>();
        
        public AddRecipe()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddRecipe_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            using (RecipeClassesDataContext dbContext = new RecipeClassesDataContext())
            {
                dgvAvailIngredients.DataSource = dbContext.Ingredients.OfType<Ingredient>().ToList();
                this.dgvRecipeIngredients.DataSource = selectedIngredients;
                   
                formatPage();
                txtTotCals.Text = "0";
                txtTotCarbs.Text = "0";
                txtTotProtein.Text = "0";
                txtTotFat.Text = "0";   
            }    
        }

        private void dgvRecipeIngredients_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            using (RecipeClassesDataContext dbContext = new RecipeClassesDataContext())
            {
                idxSelectedIngr = e.RowIndex;
                ingrId = Convert.ToInt32(dgvRecipeIngredients.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);

                //var ingr = (from r in dbContext.Ingredients where r.IngredientId == ingrId select r).First();
                //txtAddIngredient.Text = ingr.Name;
                //txtAddUnit.Text = ingr.Units;
                //txtAddAmount.Text = ingr.Amount.ToString();
            } 
        }

        private void dgvAvailIngredients_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            using (RecipeClassesDataContext dbContext = new RecipeClassesDataContext())
            {
                idxSelectedAvailIngr = e.RowIndex;
                availIngrId = Convert.ToInt32(dgvAvailIngredients.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);

                var ingr = (from r in dbContext.Ingredients where r.IngredientId == availIngrId select r).First();
                txtAddIngredient.Text = ingr.Name;
                txtAddUnit.Text = ingr.Units;
                txtAddAmount.Text = ingr.Amount.ToString();
            }    
        }
        private void bnAddIngredient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (RecipeClassesDataContext dbContext = new RecipeClassesDataContext())
            {
                var ingr = (from r in dbContext.Ingredients where r.IngredientId == availIngrId select r).First();

                if (availIngrId > 0)
                {
                    float amountNumber = 0;
                    bool amountValid = float.TryParse(txtAddAmount.Text, out amountNumber);
                    if (amountValid == false)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please only use numbers in the amount box.");
                        return;
                    }

                    ingr.Amount = amountNumber;
                    selectedIngredients.Add(ingr);
                    
                    txtAddIngredient.Text = "";
                    txtAddUnit.Text = "";
                    txtAddAmount.Text = "";

                    dgvRecipeIngredients.DataSource = null;
                    dgvRecipeIngredients.DataSource = selectedIngredients;


                    //TODO This is where the code to multiply the amount happens, then add the ingredient to the recipe. 
                    //Includes updating recipe nutrients.

                    float ingrcals = ingr.Calories * ingr.Amount;
                    float ingrcarbs = ingr.Calories * ingr.Amount;
                    float ingrpro = ingr.Protein * ingr.Amount;
                    float ingrfat = ingr.Fat * ingr.Amount;

                    float totcals = float.Parse(txtTotCals.Text);
                    float totcarbs = float.Parse(txtTotCarbs.Text);
                    float totpro = float.Parse(txtTotProtein.Text);
                    float totfat = float.Parse(txtTotFat.Text);

                    txtTotCals.Text = (totcals + ingrcals).ToString();
                    txtTotCarbs.Text = (totcarbs + ingrcarbs).ToString();
                    txtTotProtein.Text = (totpro + ingrpro).ToString();
                    txtTotFat.Text = (totfat + ingrfat).ToString();

                }
                else { MessageBox.Show("Please select an ingredient to add."); }

            }
        }


        private void bnSaveRecipe_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //TODO save recipe
            using (RecipeClassesDataContext dbContext = new RecipeClassesDataContext())
            {

                Recipe r = new Recipe();

                if (ValidateForm())
                {
                    r.Name = txtRecName.Text;
                    r.Dish = cbDish.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    r.Servings = Int32.Parse(txtServings.Text);
                    r.TotalCalories = Int32.Parse(txtTotCals.Text);
                    r.TotalFat = Int32.Parse(txtTotFat.Text);
                    r.TotalCarbs = Int32.Parse(txtTotCarbs.Text);
                    r.TotalProtein = Int32.Parse(txtTotProtein.Text);
                    r.Instructions = rtxtInstructions.Text;

                    dbContext.Recipes.InsertOnSubmit(r);
                    dbContext.SubmitChanges();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record is saved", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    int id = r.RecipeId;

                    // r.IngredientList = selectedIngredients;

                    IngredientList il = new IngredientList();
                    foreach (Ingredient ingr in selectedIngredients)
                    {
                        il.RecipeId = id;
                        il.IngredientId = ingr.IngredientId;
                        il.IngredientAmount = ingr.Amount;
                    }


                    txtRecName.Text = "";
                    txtServings.Text = "";
                    txtTotCals.Text = "0";
                    txtTotFat.Text = "0";
                    txtTotCarbs.Text = "0";
                    txtTotProtein.Text = "0";
                    rtxtInstructions.Text = "";
                    dgvRecipeIngredients.DataSource = null;
                    dgvRecipeIngredients.DataSource = selectedIngredients;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all boxes on form with valid values.");
                }
            }


        }

        private bool ValidateForm()
        {
            bool output = true;

            if (txtRecName.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                output = false;
            }

            if (cbDish.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                output = false;
            }


            int servingsNumber = 0;
            bool servingsValid = int.TryParse(txtServings.Text, out servingsNumber);
            if (servingsValid == false)
            {
                output = false;
            }

            int caloriesNumber = 0;
            bool caloriesValid = int.TryParse(txtTotCals.Text, out caloriesNumber);
            if (caloriesValid == false)
            {
                output = false;
            }

            int fatNumber = 0;
            bool fatValid = int.TryParse(txtTotFat.Text, out fatNumber);
            if (fatValid == false)
            {
                output = false;
            }

            int carbsNumber = 0;
            bool carbsValid = int.TryParse(txtTotCarbs.Text, out carbsNumber);
            if (carbsValid == false)
            {
                output = false;
            }

            int proteinNumber = 0;
            bool proteinValid = int.TryParse(txtTotProtein.Text, out proteinNumber);
            if (proteinValid == false)
            {
                output = false;
            }

            return output;
        }

        private void btnAddCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //TODO Change from exit to cancel
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void bnDelIngr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //TODO - Add code to remove Nutrition info for removed ingredient - this is done, but it doesn't reomove the item from the list yet.

            using (RecipeClassesDataContext dbContext = new RecipeClassesDataContext())
            {
                var ingr = (from r in dbContext.Ingredients where r.IngredientId == ingrId select r).First();

                if (ingrId > 0)
                {

                    float ingrcals = ingr.Calories * ingr.Amount;
                    float ingrcarbs = ingr.Calories * ingr.Amount;
                    float ingrpro = ingr.Protein * ingr.Amount;
                    float ingrfat = ingr.Fat * ingr.Amount;

                    float totcals = float.Parse(txtTotCals.Text);
                    float totcarbs = float.Parse(txtTotCarbs.Text);
                    float totpro = float.Parse(txtTotProtein.Text);
                    float totfat = float.Parse(txtTotFat.Text);

                    txtTotCals.Text = (totcals - ingrcals).ToString();
                    txtTotCarbs.Text = (totcarbs - ingrcarbs).ToString();
                    txtTotProtein.Text = (totpro - ingrpro).ToString();
                    txtTotFat.Text = (totfat - ingrfat).ToString();

                    ingr.Amount = 1;
                    selectedIngredients.Remove(ingr);

                    dgvRecipeIngredients.DataSource = null;
                    dgvRecipeIngredients.DataSource = selectedIngredients;
                }
                else { MessageBox.Show("Please select an ingredient to delete."); }

            }
        }

        private void bnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (RecipeClassesDataContext dbContext = new RecipeClassesDataContext())
            {
                //TODO - Add code to remove Nutrition info for Edited ingredient - this is done, but it doesn't reomove the item from the list yet.
                var ingr = (from r in dbContext.Ingredients where r.IngredientId == ingrId select r).First();

                if (ingrId >0)
                {
                    txtAddIngredient.Text = ingr.Name;
                    txtAddUnit.Text = ingr.Units;
                    txtAddAmount.Text = ingr.Amount.ToString();

                    float ingrcals = ingr.Calories * ingr.Amount;
                    float ingrcarbs = ingr.Calories * ingr.Amount;
                    float ingrpro = ingr.Protein * ingr.Amount;
                    float ingrfat = ingr.Fat * ingr.Amount;

                    float totcals = float.Parse(txtTotCals.Text);
                    float totcarbs = float.Parse(txtTotCarbs.Text);
                    float totpro = float.Parse(txtTotProtein.Text);
                    float totfat = float.Parse(txtTotFat.Text);

                    txtTotCals.Text = (totcals - ingrcals).ToString();
                    txtTotCarbs.Text = (totcarbs - ingrcarbs).ToString();
                    txtTotProtein.Text = (totpro - ingrpro).ToString();
                    txtTotFat.Text = (totfat - ingrfat).ToString();
                    
                    selectedIngredients.Remove(ingr);

                    dgvRecipeIngredients.DataSource = null;
                    dgvRecipeIngredients.DataSource = selectedIngredients;
                }
                else { MessageBox.Show("Please select an ingredient to edit."); }
            }
                
        }

        private void formatPage()
        {
            dgvAvailIngredients.Columns[0].Width = 25;
            dgvAvailIngredients.Columns[1].Width = 150;
            dgvAvailIngredients.Columns[2].Width = 75;
            dgvAvailIngredients.Columns[3].Width = 25;
            dgvAvailIngredients.Columns[4].Width = 50;
            dgvAvailIngredients.Columns[5].Width = 50;
            dgvAvailIngredients.Columns[6].Width = 50;
            dgvAvailIngredients.Columns[7].Width = 50;

            dgvRecipeIngredients.Columns[0].Width = 25;
            dgvRecipeIngredients.Columns[1].Width = 150;
            dgvRecipeIngredients.Columns[2].Width = 75;
            dgvRecipeIngredients.Columns[3].Width = 25;
            dgvRecipeIngredients.Columns[4].Width = 50;
            dgvRecipeIngredients.Columns[5].Width = 50;
            dgvRecipeIngredients.Columns[6].Width = 50;
            dgvRecipeIngredients.Columns[7].Width = 50;

        }

        private void btnSearchIngr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string srch = txtSearchIngr.Text;
            using (RecipeClassesDataContext dbContext = new RecipeClassesDataContext())
            {
                var ingrlist = from r in dbContext.Ingredients where r.Name.Contains(srch) select r;
                dgvAvailIngredients.DataSource = ingrlist;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Ingredient is being pulled from LINQ to SQL tables. Ingredient is actually an abstract class, with HealthyIngredient and RegularIngredient subclasses, but both subclasses are stored in the same SQL table, with null values in the places where the other subclass has its specific values.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ingredient] (
[IngredientId]    INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]            VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Units]           NCHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
[Amount]          FLOAT           DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
[Calories]        INT           NOT NULL,
[Fat]             INT           NOT NULL,
[Carbs]           INT           NOT NULL,
[Protein]         INT           NOT NULL,
[Discriminator]   NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[HealthyVariant1] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[HealthyVariant2] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[HealthyType]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[RegularVariant]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[HealthyVar1Id]   INT           NULL,
[HealthyVar2Id]   INT           NULL,
[RegVarId]        INT           NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IngredientId] ASC)
```

This also seems to work just fine, including a bunch of fairly complicated math involving multiplying inserted fields of the table and adding them to text boxes elsewhere on the form, and changing some info between the first grid and the second, so the data is all being passed correctly to the second datagrid.

However, if I try to select anything from the second datagrid, I get an error that crashes the whole program and sends it all the way back to the Program.cs.

Strangely enough, every once in a while if I have the datagrid set to RowHeadderSelect and I only click on the row header, it works correctly, including letting me use the edit button and doing the math correctly again, and then it works during that session no matter where I click, but then when I restart the program it gives me the same error again.

I have tried List, IList, ICollection, and IEnumerable, just in case it was my list type causing the issue, but it doesn’t seem to be. Anyone have some suggestions about what I am doing wrong?

I have added more of the relevant code. These are the only three methods that affect anything at the moment - the Load, the Add, and then trying to click on the datagridview.

I don't know where to put any debugging code, since it crashes before it enters the CellContentClick method. I have a breakpoint there but it never reaches it. I am thinking that it is what or how I am loading the data, but it all looks right in the datagrid on the page. Is there a different way I should be setting up the data to the datagrid? Thanks for helping.

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException
  HResult=0x80131508
  Message=Index -1 does not have a value.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Current()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCell& dataGridViewCell, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean canCreateNewRow, Boolean validationFailureOccurred)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean setAnchorCellAddress, Boolean validateCurrentCell, Boolean throughMouseClick)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowHeaderMouseDown(HitTestInfo hti, Boolean isShiftDown, Boolean isControlDown)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at HealthierRecipes.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Tania\source\repos\Old\HealthierRecipes\HealthierRecipes\Program.cs:line 25
```

Comment: You need a better trace of the code. The error seems pretty clear… an index is out of range. From the posted code, this error could only come from one place… `dgvRecipeIngredients.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value` … and given the context in which the code is executed… the grids `CellContentClick` … I doubt that `e.Row` or cell zero (0) is invalid considering the cell MUST exist in order to fire the event. It appears there may be numerous events wired up to the grid. Add `Debug.Writeline` statements at the beginning and end of each event to help figure out where the error is coming from.

Comment: Hi John G -I just put in ALL code on the whole AddRecipeis.cs page. Yes, it does not matter where I click, it crashes. The only time I have had it not crash is occasionally when I have clicked on the Row Header where it doesn't have any text at all, if I have the  RowHeaderSelect turned on, but that still only works sometimes, and still crashes if I click anywhere else. I will work on trying the Debug statements. I also have CellClick and CellContentClick both wired up to go to the same method. I can send you a Google Drive link to the whole project if you want to play with it. Thank you.

Comment: I have tested with one and both on the DGV that is working, and it doesn't seem to have any ill affects, but I will try to check further. I have done this before, just to make sure that wherever a person clicks it will register. I would like to have an option for "Anywhere in the row" since I have "Whole row selection" on, but there doesn't seem to be a place for that.

Comment: I have added a picture of my user interface so you have a better visual on how it works. The only way to get data into the second (bottom) grid where I am having the issue is to use the Add button. The top grid is all of the available ingredients, the bottom one is the ingredients that the user has added for this recipe. Also, my Add Ingredient page uses the same variables in the same way, and that page doesn't crash, nor does the upper grid. That is why I am wondering if it is how I am adding the data to the grid that is the problem. I am not sure what data you had in the second grid.

Comment: Changed to CellClick only on both grids. Tested on first grid, works fine, did not affect issue with second grid. 
Clicking on the Column Header row on grid 1 gets an “Index was out of range.” error. 
Clicking it with nothing in grid 2 goes to the dgvRecipeIngredients_CellContentClick method breakpoint, but the header row e.rowindex is apparently -1, so it gets the “Index was out of range.” error.
Clicking on the Column Header row on grid 2 with data in it gets the same “Index -1 does not have a value.” Clicking anywhere else when there was no data didn’t do anything.

Comment: Turned on the Debug statements at the beginning and end of the bnAddIngredient and dgvRecipeIngredients_CellContentClick. I added 3 ingredients, then clicked on one. It entered and left Add just fine all 3 times, and crashed before it ever entered CellContentClick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a few tests, I broke this down and can post a very simple example to reproduce what you describe. But for grins...

In the forms “Load” event there is a line that sets the recipe ingredient grid’s data source…

```
this.dgvRecipeIngredients.DataSource = selectedIngredients;
```

---

> // Comment out that line.

---

We do not need to set grids data source at this time since the list is empty. It will get set when the add button is clicked.

Please try this and let me know if this helps.

> This looks like another good example where a `BindingList<T>` is a
> better choice.

Comment: Yes, getting rid of that line fixed the error. I had it in there so I could format the grid columns, but as soon as I put anything in the grid they were unformatting anyway. I think the answer I was really looking for was the BindingList<T>. I thought there should have been a better way to do things, I just didn't know what it was. THANK YOU!

Comment: JohnG, BindingList<T> worked perfectly. That was the answer I was looking for. Thank you so much for all of your time. I put what I did at the top of the page for others to see. I don't have enough points on StackOverflow to upvote the answer, so I have asked others to do so. THANK YOU again.

Comment: I took me a bit to figure it out, however I was able to learn more about Entity framework. I could swear I have done this before using a simple `List<T>`. But obviously I am mistaken. In any case it appears obvious that using a `BindingList<T>` has many advantages over a `List<T>.` Glad it worked with a simple fix. I reference to your last comment… You can up vote when you have the rep, however, since it is your question, you can mark it as answered… [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) … you get some points too.